# I want to call smart contract method function at php on tron blockchain

Tags: blockchain, tron

I have deployed smart contract on tron.
I want to call smart contract method function at php on tron blockchain.
please help me.
My skype id is live:.cid.6f4ac54533c89f00
Thank you.

Comment: Please, give us an example code of what have you tried. Also, remove you skype id.

Answer (score 0):

There is [PHP SDK for Tron API](https://github.com/iexbase/tron-api) and you can use it but I think a better way is to use [Tron HTTP API](https://developers.tron.network/reference#api-overview) with CURL.

Comment: But there is not method function to call contract method on tron blockcahin.